# Немудрящий и немудреный — в чем разница?

Tags: лексика, стилистика

Из **современной** художественной литературы:

*Николас читал много интересного про московский метрополитен, станции которого зачем-то выстроены в виде помпезных дворцов, но нелепо было бы начать знакомство с городом, про который столько слышал и читал, с подземки. Поэтому, выйдя из своей гостиницы (некрасивый стеклянный параллелепипед, до невозможности портящий вид Тверской улицы, да и номера хуже, чем в самом **немудрящем** «бед-энд-брекфасте»), Николас мельком взглянул на красную стену Кремля (потом, это потом) и двинулся по карте в юго-западном направлении.*

Какое **значение и стилевая** характеристика у слова "немудрящий"? Оно устарело, это просторечие? Почему писатель использовал его в **современной** литературе?

Comment: немудр**и**щИ, немудрищём - это сленг образованный путём соединения усеченных основ "не му***и" и "не дрищи", то есть цивильная гостиница для чётких пацанов, а не всяких чушпанов.

Comment: Оригинальное мнение! А чушпаны – это кто?  Ваше изобретение?

Comment: да ну нет конечно, это же из сериала, который везде пиарят и все смотрели.

Comment: Я не смотрела, а надо бы. А то много потеряла.  Как бы вы определили это слово?  Николас – мой любимый герой, если что.

Comment: Если не смотрели, то пока не потеряли) нельзя потерять то, с чем дело не имел.

Comment: А если ближе к лингвистике...  Он, кстати, маргинальную лексику изучал в университете, а не где-нибудь.

Comment: Кто именно? и что ближе?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Гостиницы типа «Bed & Breakfast» прочно занимают свою нишу, потому и немудрящи: они и так приносят владельцу большой доход. В этом слове — немудрящий — есть смысловая доля причастия *не мудрствующий* (*лукаво*), т.е. не отклоняющийся от нормы, не блуждающий в помыслах, способный не соблазняясь идти прямо. Она о предшествующем воспитании и самовоспитании. Это трудно.

Немудрёный прост, лёгок, простодушен, неумён — не приучен *мудрствовать*. Немудрёные инструменты, приборы, вещи... если и бывают хороши, то только по-своему. Как была хороша гостиница-параллелепипед.

Comment: Спасибо, интересно!

Comment: С наступающим не мудрствующим президентом!